# I am trying to add the state line of Arkansas. I would also like the zip code to display when you scroll over it. I am using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am pretty new to R and am trying to get the state line of Arkansas to show up, as well as the zip codes to display when scrolled over. I am using ggplot. Here is the code I created:

```
Arkansas <- acs_medicare_2017_2013 %>% 
  filter(`nppes_provider_state.x` == 'AR') %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(NAME, "^9|^8|^75501")) 

zcta_geodata_shifted <- get_acs(geography = "zcta", 
                                variables = "B01001_001", 
                                geometry = TRUE)
```

```
AR_join <- zcta_geodata_shifted %>% 
  inner_join(Arkansas, by = c("GEOID" = "NAME"))
```

```
 AR_join %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = `percentage change`)) +
  geom_sf(lwd = 0) +
  theme_map() +
  labs(fill='Percentage Change',title="AR", subtitle = "2013-2017", 
       caption = "Source: U.S. Census ACS") +
  theme(legend.position="right") +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma", labels = comma)
```